# Nested table view in ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating nested table view. One table view for vertical scrolling. And another for horizontal scrolling inside the cell of first. I set the delegate of horizontal table view to vertical table view's cell subclass. But the problem is that the horizontal table view's delegate methods aren't calling.
Does any one have an idea why its not calling?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are setting the delegate programatically when configuring the cell that contains the second tableview.

Can you post some code...